# Building OSgi Web app bundle with Primefaces on glassfish - NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/context/FacesContextFactory

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, glassfish, osgi

I'm trying to get my OSGi WAB to work, but kept either getting `NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/context/FacesContextFactory` or `FacesContexFactory was not configured properly`.

I got the first error when I do not include the `javax.faces.jar` in my `war`'s `WEB-INF/lib` file and let the application use the one that comes with glassfish and also set class-laoder to use delegate in `glassfish-web.xml`.

Because of that, I figured, maybe I should include the `javax.faces.jar` in the `war` but then I get the `FacesContexFactory was not configured properly` error.
I've been Googling around and have NOT been able to find anything useful. Any suggestion?

Here's my configs:

`web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Servlet Config -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- jsf mapping -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Welcome page -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>pages/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>        
</web-app>
```

`glassfish-web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <context-root>/helloWorld</context-root>
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

`MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Manifest-Verion: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-SymbolicName: HelloWorld
Bundle-Version: 0.1.0.SNAPSHOT
Bundle-Name: Simulation Vis
Import-Package: javax.servlet,
 javax.servlet.http,
 javax.ws.rs,
 javax.ws.rs.core,
 org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0"
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 WEB-INF/classes,
 WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-5.3.jar
Web-ContextPath: /helloWorld
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Bundle-Activator: my.Activator
Require-Bundle: tests.service;bundle-version="0.1.0";visibility:=reexport
Bundle-Vendor: Foo Bar
```

Comment: i think that primefaces is based on jsf 2.2 but glashfish 3.1 doesnt have factory support for jsf 2.2. you need to manually "upgrade" the jars or use a newer version of glassfish.

Comment: my mistake. as i just saw, 5.3 also supports 2.0 and 2.1 version.